# What semantic notions underlie 'join together' and 'impose, inflict' (ie injunct)?

Tags: etymology, english

I'm trying to understand the etymology of [injunction](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=injunct).  To wit, how did

> *in-* "on" (from PIE root [*en](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*en) "in")
>    + *iungere* "to join together" (from nasalized form of PIE root [*yeug-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*yeug-) "to join")

compound to mean

> Late Latin *iniunctionem* (nominative *iniunctio*) "a command,"

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Jungere* means to bind things together. With the *in-* "into, onto" prefix, it means to attach one thing onto something else.

Literally, this is used for physical objects, like vines joining themselves onto a wall. But metaphorically, it can mean to attach new restrictions or punishments onto someone.

Thus, an *injunction* is when these restrictions and commands are attached to someone.

EDIT: In the comments, Cerberus has pointed out a connection with *jugum* "yoke", which is another nice analogy for a punishment attached to someone.